# combining two xml's in xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have two XML's in which one contains the conditions and the other xml contains the list of error codes which has to be assigned to the resulting XML based on the evaluation of the conditions.

**Conditions.xml**

```
<Validations>   
<Condition-1>UPDATE-IND!=A</Condition-1>   
<Condition-2>DUP-OVERRIDE=B</Condition-2>   
<Condition-3>TYPE-RECORD!=R</Condition-3>
</Validations>
```

**ErrorList.xml**

```
<ErrorList>
<error>
    <errorcode>1</errorcode>
    <errordescription>UPDATE INDICATOR.</errordescription>
</error>
<error>
    <errorcode>2</errorcode>
    <errordescription>SHOULD NOT BE BLANK.</errordescription>
</error>
<error>
    <errorcode>3</errorcode>
    <errordescription>NOT IN LIST</errordescription>
</error>
<error>
    <errorcode>4</errorcode>
    <errordescription>PARSE ERROR.</errordescription>
</error>
```

**Input XML:**

```
<a>
    <c>
        <UPDATE-IND>A</UPDATE-IND>
        <DUP-OVERRIDE>B</DUP-OVERRIDE>
        <TYPE-RECORD>R</TYPE-RECORD>
    </c>
</a>
```

In XSLT the resulting xml should be like

when condition 1 is true (from Conditions.xml) 1st set of error code's from ErrorList.xml should be displayed in the resulting xml. Likewise for all the conditions which are satisfied the relevant **error** nodes should be displayed in my final xml.

How to write XSLT for this? I have been trying to use document() function, but couldn't figure out how to iterate through all the conditions and error codes at the same time to form the final XML.

**Note**: I'm trying this in my Tibco BW with Saxon-B XSLT 2.0 as transform engine.

**New Logic:**

Instead of combining two XML's, I'm trying to make use of a single xml which contains both conditions and error codes.

Input XML remains the same.

Conditions XML:

```
<ns0:root xmlns:ns0 = "http://www.tibco.com/schemas/Validation.xsd">
<ns0:subElement1 ID = "id">
    <ns0:subElement2 ID = "id">
        <ns0:subElement3 ID = "id">
            <ns0:subElement4 ID = "id">
                <ns0:subElement5 cond = "1">
                    <ns0:conditions>1=1</ns0:conditions>
                    <ns0:errorcode>001</ns0:errorcode>
                </ns0:subElement5>
                <ns0:subElement5 cond = "2">
                    <ns0:conditions>2=2</ns0:conditions>
                    <ns0:errorcode>002</ns0:errorcode>
                </ns0:subElement5>
                <ns0:subElement5 cond = "3">
                    <ns0:conditions>3!=3</ns0:conditions>
                    <ns0:errorcode>003</ns0:errorcode>
                </ns0:subElement5>
            </ns0:subElement4>
        </ns0:subElement3>
    </ns0:subElement2>
</ns0:subElement1>
```

Now I'm trying to get the condition, evaluate it and get the relevant error code from same xml.

**Note:** The conditions.xml is passed as Input parameter to the XSLT.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And is this what you want? If the value (`1=1`) of `Condition-1` is true, then show `errordescription` of `errorcode` equal to 1? So the part after `-` indicates which error code should be used?

Comment: No '-' has no significance here. I'll be evaluating the condition with saxon:evaluate() function. If the first condition is true, 1st set of error node should be displayed likewise it should be evaluated for all the conditions in the XML. There will be equal number of conditions and errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select elements simply based on the position then use

```
<xsl:param name="error-url" select="'ErrorList.xml'"/>

<xsl:variable name="errors" select="doc($error-url)/ErrorList/error"/>

<xsl:template match="Validations">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Validations/*">
  <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
  <xsl:if test="saxon:evaluate(.)">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$errors[$pos]"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is a more complete sample. Assuming we have the main input as

```
<a>
    <c>
        <UPDATE-IND>A</UPDATE-IND>
        <DUP-OVERRIDE>B</DUP-OVERRIDE>
        <TYPE-RECORD>R</TYPE-RECORD>
    </c>
</a>
```

and `test2013110502.xml` as

```
<Validations>   
<Condition-1>UPDATE-IND!='A'</Condition-1>   
<Condition-2>DUP-OVERRIDE='B'</Condition-2>   
<Condition-3>TYPE-RECORD!='R'</Condition-3>
</Validations>
```

(note the change to your sample, the right hand side has string literals) and the file `test2013110503.xml` as

```
<ErrorList>
<error>
    <errorcode>1</errorcode>
    <errordescription>UPDATE INDICATOR.</errordescription>
</error>
<error>
    <errorcode>2</errorcode>
    <errordescription>SHOULD NOT BE BLANK.</errordescription>
</error>
<error>
    <errorcode>3</errorcode>
    <errordescription>NOT IN LIST</errordescription>
</error>
<error>
    <errorcode>4</errorcode>
    <errordescription>PARSE ERROR.</errordescription>
</error>
</ErrorList>
```

the stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs saxon">

<xsl:param name="conditions-url" as="xs:string" select="'test2013110502.xml'"/>
<xsl:param name="conditions" as="document-node()" select="doc($conditions-url)"/>

<xsl:param name="error-url" as="xs:string" select="'test2013110503.xml'"/>
<xsl:param name="errors" as="document-node()" select="doc($error-url)"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="c">
  <errors>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$conditions/Validations/*">
      <xsl:with-param name="context" select="current()"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </errors>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Validations/*">
  <xsl:param name="context"/>
  <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$context" mode="eval">
    <xsl:with-param name="expression" select="string(current())"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c" mode="eval">
  <xsl:param name="expression"/>
  <xsl:param name="pos"/>
  <xsl:if test="saxon:evaluate($expression)">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$errors/ErrorList/error[$pos]"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

outputs

```
<errors>
   <error>
      <errorcode>2</errorcode>
      <errordescription>SHOULD NOT BE BLANK.</errordescription>
   </error>
</errors>
```

The same should be possible with an XSLT 1.0 processor supporting the EXSLT `dyn:evaluate` function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
  xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
  exclude-result-prefixes="dyn">

<xsl:param name="conditions-url" select="'test2013110502.xml'"/>
<xsl:param name="conditions" select="document($conditions-url)"/>

<xsl:param name="error-url" select="'test2013110503.xml'"/>
<xsl:param name="errors" select="document($error-url)"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="c">
  <errors>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$conditions/Validations/*">
      <xsl:with-param name="context" select="current()"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </errors>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Validations/*">
  <xsl:param name="context"/>
  <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$context" mode="eval">
    <xsl:with-param name="expression" select="string(current())"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c" mode="eval">
  <xsl:param name="expression"/>
  <xsl:param name="pos"/>
  <xsl:if test="dyn:evaluate($expression)">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$errors/ErrorList/error[$pos]"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the result

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<errors>
  <error>
    <errorcode>2</errorcode>
    <errordescription>SHOULD NOT BE BLANK.</errordescription>
  </error>
</errors>
```

with `xsltproc`

```
Using libxml 20708, libxslt 10126 and libexslt 815
xsltproc was compiled against libxml 20706, libxslt 10126 and libexslt 815
libxslt 10126 was compiled against libxml 20706
libexslt 815 was compiled against libxml 20706
```

on Windows.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Actually Both Conditions.xml and ErrorList.xml are external sources which will be used to apply the transformations on a separate input xml. The Conditions are based on the fields from the Input xml. In that case how to change this logic?

Comment: @Guru, show us the structure of all three input samples if there is a third, main input document.

Comment: This is perfect. Dint know much about the document-node() function. Thanks a lot martin.

Comment: @Guru, `document-node()` in the `as` attribute is a type. The function used to load a secondary document is `doc`.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same logic in XSLT 1.0 using dyn:evaluate($expr) function?

Comment: @Guru, well `dyn:evaluate` is not XSLT 1.0 but an EXSLT extension that is not widely supported by XSLT processors. `xsltproc` seems to support it, I will add a sample.

Comment: I tried the above logic earlier replacing saxon with dyn, but my tibco xslt engine doesn't seem to support this extension. How to do this in xsltproc?

Comment: @Guru, well I have posted an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet that works with `xsltproc`. Of course that does not help if tibco does not use xsltproc and does not support the EXSLT `dyn:evaluate`. Find out which XSLT processor tibco uses and whether it supports the EXSLT `dyn:evaluate`.

Comment: Hi Martin, Can you please look into the updated question and suggest me how to implement the same?

Comment: I'm trying to make use of an Input XML and one parameter in the form of xml which contains both the conditions and errorcodes.